# Worksheet function Sum-if causing error type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am looping through the worksheets to sumif the amounts that are "C" and "D".

Each tabs have the amounts in column M and whether they are credit or debit in column N, indicated by the letter C or D.

First I am putting the letters C and D on blank cells and trying to sumif these two amounts next to them.

I am getting a type mismatch error at the sumif line and the whole line is highlighted.

At first I thought maybe it was ws = Worksheets(I) causing the problem so I swapped them out with Worksheets(I), but it still did not work.

```
Sub Sumiftabs()

Dim Filepath As String    
Dim UIGFile As Workbook    
Dim Column As String    
Dim Month As String    
Dim Year As Integer    
Dim I As Long    
Dim TY As Integer    
Dim TYLetter As String    
Dim T As Long
Dim TreatyYear As Long    
Dim WS_Count As Integer    
Dim ws As Worksheet


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

TreatyYear = Sheets("Control").Range("B7").Value

'On Error Resume Next

For T = TreatyYear To 16 Step -1    
TYLetter = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(T, Workbooks("Separate tabs.xlsm").Sheets("Control").Range("H:I"), 2, False)    
TY = Sheets("Control").Range("B7").Value    
Month = Sheets("Control").Range("B5").Value    
Year = Sheets("Control").Range("B4").Value    
Filepath = Sheets("Control").Range("B2").Value    

Set UIGFile = Workbooks.Open("K:\Ayoon\UIG\" & Year & "\" & Month & "\UIG_NSA_MonYear_TY" & T & ".xls")

WS_Count = UIGFile.Worksheets.Count

For I = WS_Count To 1 Step -1

Set ws = Worksheets(I)

'Direct Premium
UIGFile.Worksheets(I).Range("S4").Value = "C"    
UIGFile.Worksheets(I).Range("S5").Value = "D"    
UIGFile.Worksheets(I).Range("T4").Value = _
   Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range("N:N"), ws.Range("S:S"), ws.Range("M:M"))

UIGFile.Worksheets(I).Range("T5").Value = _
   Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range("N:N"), ws.Range("S:S"), ws.Range("M:M"))

Next I

UIGFile.Close savechanges:=True


Next T

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Your SUMIF looks incorrect: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: Is it because I am selecting the whole column for the criteria instead of specific criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SUMIF looks incorrect.

Eg try this instead:

```
UIGFile.Worksheets(I).Range("T4").Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Range("N:N"), "C", ws.Range("M:M"))
```

Comment: This works (I had to swap out ws with Worksheets(I) still). Do you know why I can't simply select the whole range? That's what I do on excel worksheet, but I guess it doesn't work in VBA

Comment: Sorry  - if that works on the sheet I don't know why it doesn't when using via VBA.